# Insertion in Many to Many unidirectional relationship in Spring JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables, Users, and Roles. Roles are like "ADMIN", "MANAGER","USER". Users can have of the roles. So in my java project, I have the user as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
    "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

//other data and getters and setters

}
```

My Role class is like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Integer roleId;

    @Column(name = "role_name",unique=true)
    private String role;

//getters and setters

}
```

Let's say I have inserted manually 3 records to Roles

```
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (1,'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (2,'MANAGER');
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (3,'USER');
```

Now I want to insert to User table such that only user and user_roles(join table) get inserted:

Eg:
If i want to insert an user with userId=1 and role={ADMIN,MANAGER}, an entry in user table and 2 entries in user_roles table like `(1,1)` and `(1,2)` should get inserted. There should not be any insertion to the Roles table. How do I achieve this?

I tried with changing manytomany to onetomany... Also, I tried changing cascadeType.all to CascadeType.MERGE and detach... none of them worked correctly... 
please help

//UPDATE:

Adding code related to create/update user

```
public User createUser(UserDto account) {
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setPassword(account.getPassword());
    newUser.setUsername(account.getUsername());
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    Role role = roleRepository.findByRole(account.getRole());
    if (role != null) {
        role.setRole(account.getRole());
        roles.add(role);
        newUser.setRoles(roles);
        User savedUser = save(newUser);
        return savedUser;
    }
    return null;
}

@Transactional
    public User save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        try {
            user = userRepository.save(user);
        } catch (org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return user;
    }

@Override
    public User updateUser(String oldUserName, UserDto userDto) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByUsername(oldUserName);
        optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        // if (optionalUser != null) {
        User user = optionalUser.get();
        if (user != null) {
            Set<Role> roleset = new HashSet<Role>();
            if (userDto.getRole() != null && !userDto.getRole().isEmpty()) {
                Role role = roleRepository.findByRole(userDto.getRole());
                if (role != null) {
                    roleset.add(role);
                }
            }
            user.setRoles(roleset);
            user.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
            user = userRepository.save(user);
            return user;
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

When i tried with

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

i get the following exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.techjava.springbootsecuritymysql.model.Role
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `cascade` altogether? Im not entirely sure what it does here. I think it is not needed. And: what exactly does not work? Is the user inserted but not the entries in `user_roles`? Do you get an error? How does the code where you insert the user look like?

Comment: @x4rf41 updated the question

Comment: The error states, that the role you passed is detached (which means, that it is not tracked by the hibernate entity manager anymore). I think the problem is, that you read the role outside the transaction, and then insert the association inside the transaction. Can please try two things:1. add @Transactional to the `createUser` method. 2. remove the casade from the @ManyToMany ( or set it to `cascade = {}`

Comment: Hey @x4rf41 it worked with the above steps you mentioned.. thank you..

Comment: Nice. @stallion I wrote it up in answer with a bit more explanation. Would be great if you accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `detached entity passed to persist` is caused by the role being detached from the entityManager. The reason for that is, that it is read outside the Transaction but the association in `user_roles` is inserted within the transaction.

To solve that problem simply add `@Transactional` to the `createUser` method. Then the `Role` is read in the same transaction and won't be detached:

```
@Transactional
public User createUser(UserDto account) {
//...
}
```

The other thing is, that you set the cascade on the `@ManyToMany`. This is not needed if only the associations should be automatically persisted and deleted with the `User`. They will always be automatically created and deleted no matter what the cascase options are.
Cascade would be needed when you for example want the `Role` itself to be automatically inserted with the `User` which I assume you do not want from your code sample. So just remove the cascade:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```